# Strong convergence of convex combinations of a weakly convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-convergence

Consider the Mazur's Lemma (H. Brezis - "Functional analysis, ..."):

> Assume $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$. Then there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ made up of convex combinations of the $x_n$'s that converges strongly to $x$.

The Lemma says that "there exists a sequence...''.

Is it true that **every** sequence $(y_n)$ made up of convex combinations of the $x_n$'s converges strongly to $x$?

For example, if we consider 
$$y_n = \frac{1}{n}(x_1 + x_2 + ... +x_n),$$
is it true that $y_n$ converges strongly to $x$?

Comment: Remarks: (1) [Markdown formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for bold, italic, etc, is better than text-in-Mathjax. (2) The title "question involving X" says the same thing as the title "X". Once you drop these extra words, you'll likely find how little the title actually says about the question... and come up with a more specific title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: $y_n=x_n$ is a convex combination of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Clearly, this need not converge strongly.

Longer answer: for any particular choice of coefficients one can cook up a sequence $(x_n)$ where the strong convergence of convex combinations fails. Here's an idea. For any sequence $a_n\to \infty$ we have $\sin a_n t\to 0$ weakly in $L^2[0,1]$. Choose $a_n$ such that they grow slowly, for example $a_n=\lfloor   \log_4 n\rfloor$. You will observe that when $n = 4^{k+1}-1$ for an integer $k$, most of the terms $x_j(t)=\sin a_j t$ for $1\le j\le n$ are equal to $\sin k t$; about $3/4$ of them are. So, the average can be estimated pointwise from below:
$$
|x_1+\dots+x_n|\ge \frac34n |\sin kt| - \frac14 n
$$
hence 
$$
\frac1n |x_1+\dots+x_n|\ge \frac34 |\sin kt| - \frac14
$$
This shows that $|y_n|\ge 1/4$ on the set where $|\sin kt|\ge 2/3$, and this set has measure that doesn't get small as $k\to\infty$.